# Is there a well-defined partition function of 4d Yang-Mills?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, yang-mills, partition-function

So I've looked everywhere to find a resource on 4 dimensional Yang-Mills partition functions, but have only managed to find examples using supersymmetry. Is there a resource describing the partition function of Yang-Mills without using the assumption of SUSY? If not, why isn't there?

Comment: Comment to the post (v1): At the physics level of rigor, the Yang-Mills partition function is presented in many QFT textbooks, e.g. Peskin & Schroeder, Weinberg, Srednicki, Itzykson & Zuber, etc.

Comment: For 2D Yang-Mills, exact solutions exist and are well known, cf. [Wittens *"On Quantum Gauge Theories in two dimensions"*](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1104248198) or [*"Lectures on 2D Yang-Mills Theory, Equivariant Cohomology and Topological Field Theories"* by Cordes, Moore and Ramgoolam](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9411210). You seem to not have looked "everywhere", or you should specify what *exactly* you did not find.

Comment: @Qmechanic why isn't that approach mathematically rigorous?

Comment: @ACuriousMind sorry, I meant for four dimensions

Comment: For the question of rigor - the mathematically rigorous proof of a mass-gapped 4D YM theory is [one of the millenium problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_existence_and_mass_gap).